# Javascript - Create tree structure from array of objects using a group by to define children

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects from which I would like to group by a property to build a tree structure.

```
objects = [object1, object2, object3, ... ]
```

**Object example:**

```
object1 = {
           FolderName: "Folder1",  //group on this property
           NodeName: "Node1"
          }
```

I want to group objects by the FolderName property to get a tree structure like this:

```
treeData  = [
              {
                text: "Folder1",
                nodes: [
                          {
                            text: "Node1",
                          }
                        ]
              },
              { 
                text: "Folder2",
                nodes : [
                          {
                            text: "NodeX",
                          }
                        ]
              }
            ]
```

**Edit:**

I was trying with this groupBy function but it returns an array of arrays. So I transform it into the tree structure I need with the for loop. I got the result I want but I wander how to achieve it in a more optimal way.

```
function groupBy(array, f) {
      var groups = {};
      array.forEach(function(o){
        var group = JSON.stringify(f(o));
        groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
        groups[group].push(o);
      });
      return Object.keys(groups).map(function(group){
        return groups[group]; 
      });
    }

var result = groupBy(objects, function(item){
    item.text = item.NodeName;
    return [item.FolderName];
});

var treeData = [];
for (i=0; i < result.length; i++) {
     treeData.push({ "text": result[i][0].FolderName, "nodes":result[i]});
}
```

Comment: This may help you : https://lodash.com/docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested, but try:

```
var treeData = [],
    folders = {};

objects.forEach(function(obj){
    if(obj.FolderName in folders)
        treeData[folders[obj.FolderName]].nodes.push({text:obj.NodeName});
    else 
        folders[obj.FolderName] = treeData.push({text: obj.FolderName, nodes: [{text:obj.NodeName}]}) - 1;
});
```

The idea is to create an object (`folders`) while building the tree array, which stores the `FolderName` as a property and the index of where that `FolderName` was added in the `treeData` array as the value. When adding to the tree, you check if the `folder` object has this property, and if so, add the node to the nodes array of the object stored at that value.

Comment: Good idea, very simple way to do it

Comment: You can also add a fiddle here and I can help to debug. Did you notice the - 1 to get the index? Because .push returns the new length of the array, it has to be reduced by one to get the index of the object added.

Comment: After review, your code is working perfectly. Thank you

Comment: By the way do you know a good, light, and simple js tree library?

Comment: Nah, can't say I do. Good, light, simple libraries are hard to come by for most things!